# How to understand "with" in the following sentence?

Tags: prepositions

> Not every job will end up **with** a success.

What is the meaning of "with" here? Why not use other preposition?

Could native speakers please describe the scene of this sentence for me? Thx.

Comment: In this exact context, idiomatically we're more likely to use ***in*** and discard the superfluous preposition/phrasal verb particle ***up*** and the indefinite article, giving *Not every job will end in success*. But there's nothing wrong with ***with***, and in closely-related constructions such as *Every speech ended with a standing ovation* it's actually *more* common. If you want a *semantic* justification (not always particularly helpful for established idiomatic usages like this) you could say *with = together, at the same time/place* (the *end* and the *success* coincide).

Answer (score 1):

In this exact context, idiomatically we're more likely to use ***in*** and discard the superfluous preposition/phrasal verb particle ***up***, and the indefinite article, giving *Not every job will end in success.* But there's nothing wrong with ***with***, and in closely-related constructions such as *Every speech ended with a standing ovation* it's actually *more* common.

If you want a semantic justification (not always particularly helpful for established idiomatic usages like this) you could say *with = (happening) together; at the same time/place; end result+success coincide.*

---

I already posted the above as a comment, but I thought it was worth showing these two usages...

> 1: [*Selfist humanism **starts with** optimism but **ends in** pessimism.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22starts%20with%20optimism%20but%20ends%20in%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)
>    2: [*verse 2 **starts in** an accusatory manner, with the conjunction P'1,38 but **ends with** a vindication*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22starts%20in%20an%20accusatory%22%20%22but%20ends%20with%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

..which I think illustrate just how "finely-balanced" the choice of preposition can be with *starting* and *ending [up]*. You might think there's something slightly odd about using *both* (in either sequence) within a binary juxtaposition *(A **but** B)*.

But they're are both perfectly well-formed, and in my opinion actually represent the *best* choices for the exact contexts as phrased.

---

EDIT: Despite what I originally said about "semantic justification" not always being helpful, I think [@Catija's link](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/with) on another of these interrelated questions is worth noting. It actually lists no less than 23 different ways you could understand constructions involving ***with***. But even probably the most "unintuitive" one...

> **20** used to show who or what a strong wish or order concerns
>    *Down with school!*
>    *Off to bed with you!*

...can be "understood" as meaning *let these two things (being down/going off to bed and school/you) **be together, coexist*** - they're just metaphoric extensions from *Do you want fries **with** your burger?*